# Pentaho PDI 9.2 will not launch

Tags: etl, pentaho, pdi

I have been PDI for years and I have been using PDI 9.1 since its release. I recently loaded PDI 9.2 and on launching spoon.bat, the windows dialog opens shows where context with the commands but then the application terminates. No error messages after launching, just nothing.

I have been running PDI on Windows 8 and lately MS Server 2016 without any issues.

Does anyone have a good place for me to start looking?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: run spoon.bat from the command line, you may see an error message there. And check the components reference here: https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.2/Setup/Components_Reference . You may be running into a compatiblity issue with e.g. Java, PDI is certified for Java 8 (including OpenJDK), not newer versions, even if they may have worked in the past.

Comment: Dirk

Thank you for your response. Actually I did run from a command line and the same behavior where there was no error message presented. The batch file launched displayed those messages and then displayed the command prompt.

I agree it is a compatibility issue but just can't figure what happened. I know that I upgraded Java right around that time but I have not had the time to dive into troubleshooting.

Thank you Ray

Comment: Try running spoon_debug.bat file and then you will have a debug log generated in the same folder location in form of text file.